# If |$G|=p^3$ and $|Z(G)|\ge p^2$, prove that G is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If |$G|=p^3$ and $|Z(G)|\ge p^2$, prove that G is abelian

**As my idea**

If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian

since $|Z(G)|\ge p^2$  then $|Z(G)|=p^2,p^3$

then $G/Z(G)=p,1$ so cyclic then G is abelian

is  am correct

Comment: You is correct.

Comment: Looks good to me.